# Assign line a variable name Unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I'm currently reading in a file of three letter strings in unix and was wondering how I would go about making the lines variables so that I can grep them in the code...

My idea goes something like this:

```
!#/bin/bash

IFS=''
while read line
  do
    code=$(line) 
    #This would be where I want to assign the line a variable
    grep "$code" final.txt >  deptandcourse.txt 
    #This is where I would want to grep according to that three letter string
done < strings.txt
```

Sample file (strings.txt):

```
ABC
BCA
BDC
```

I would like to put these letters in the variable line and then grep the file (final.txt) first for 'ABC', then 'BCA', then 'BDC'

Comment: `line` is a variable now.  What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Give sample text, and how you like to output to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line` is a variable you've set to contain the contents of each line of the file your reading from throughout the loop, so you don't need to reassign it to another variable.  See [this page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more information on using `read` in a loop.

Also, it looks like you might want to append to `deptandcourse.txt` with `>>` as using the `>` redirect will overwrite the file each time.

Maybe this is what you want:

```
while read -r line
  do 
    grep "$line" final.txt >> deptandcourse.txt 
done < strings.txt
```

As **@JohnZwinck** suggested in his comment:

```
grep -f strings.txt final.txt > deptandcourse.txt
```

which seems to be the best solution.

You could also use `awk` to accomplish the same thing:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {
    a[$0]
    next
}
{
    for(i in a)
        if($0 ~ i)
             print
}' strings.txt final.txt > deptandcourse.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! this is what I wanted to do!

Comment: @user3875711: it sort of seems like what you actually want is this one-liner: `grep -f strings.txt final.txt`.  No?

Comment: @user3875711 Agreed, `grep-f` would be better.  Write that as an answer and I'll upvote it.